# How to omit file path compression?

Tags: c#, file, path, environment-variables, compression

I have a process that injects environment variables while the process is running and all that works fine. However, when I expand one of the environment variables (`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables` in C#) sometimes I get a compressed value of the file path:

```
d:\progra~1\mifbef~1...
```

instead of

```
d:\Program Files\...
```

Functionally it is a valid path and I can `cd` to it. But I want it to be uncompressed value. Any ideas where to start troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) method will expand compressed paths.

```
string uncompressedPath = Path.GetFullPath(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%TEMP%"));
```